# Firebase Analytics iOS Valid Auto Renew Subscription Local Receipt Validation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

My iOS app (Objective C) has an autorenewing subscription implemented, which I was using `RMAppReceipt` to validate the receipts for a valid subscription locally. Was working fine.

But I had to install Firebase in my App, which permanently broke `RMAppReceipt` because of the conflicts between `OpenSSL` and `BoringSSL`.

I'm trying to find another ObjC solution to get receipts from Apple and verify them locally. I noticed that Firebase Analytics automatically goes through my local receipts at startup, and automatically logs something like this for each receipt it finds.

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023141] Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported. Product ID: 0001
```

Is there an API for doing local receipt validation with Firebase? I couldn't find any information about this in my many searches.

If not, are there any other solutions anyone would recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend for everyone, but there is also an ugly workaround described at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6111

Comment: Sorry, getting back to this project, which I put in a drawer. Is there any way to stop Firebase from spitting these messages out at start up (there are quite a number of them as it analyzes a ton of sandbox subscription test purchases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API from Firebase to do local receipt validation. It is not recommended to verify the receipt locally and you may need to write your own, or you may want to use some open-sourced 3rd party library but keep in mind that they could be compromised.